# Unable to use ADWords API

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-ads-api

I am following the instruction from the link: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/first-request here. But I am stuck in the first step itself. In python the documentation states to authenticate use the snippet

```
from adspygoogle.adwords.AdWordsClient import AdWordsClient
from adspygoogle.common import Utils
client = AdWordsClient(path=os.path.join('..', '..', '..', '..'))
```

Where I think the path contains `client_secrets.json`. The file `client_secrets.json`  exists in my location yet I get

```
ValidationError: Authentication data is missing.
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. The only problem I can think of is that I may also require developer token with it but how do I get the developer token, it doesn't exist at my MCC path also how would I use the developer token, what file-name to use for storing the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separately apply for a developer token - read this: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/signingup

Take a look at [AdWords scripts](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/), as it may be an easier way to talk to AdWords programmatically.